# Join two table where one table has relation with many table

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, relational-database

I have 5 table, and the structure is below --

```
user - id
     - name
     - dob
     - phone

desi - id
     - desgname
     - dept_id

dept - id
     - deptname
     - org_id

org  - id
     - orgname

junction_table    - id
                  - userid
                  - desg_id
                  - dept_id
                  - org_id
```

How could I make a joint table?

## update

After trying sometime, I got a solution and i posted it as answer

Comment: What do you mean joint table?? Are you saying you want to join the table??

Comment: I want to run a join query - to make a table with all the information designation, department, organization with user table.

Comment: does the junction table exist? select from that table join on the others from there and specify the columns you want. have a go at writing a query before posting

Comment: This is not clear. Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes clearly saying how output is a function of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is to left join the junction table to user table and then again left join to junction table to other table

```
SELECT
U.name,
O.orgname,
DPT.dpt,
D.desgname
FROM user U
LEFT JOIN junction_table JT
    ON U.id = JT.user_id
LEFT JOIN organization O
    ON JT.org_id = O.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_suborg DPT
    ON JT.dpt_id = DPT.id
LEFT JOIN designation D
    ON JT.desg_id = D.id
```

Thanks brother for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $this->db->select('your-selection');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->join('designation','user.designation_id=designation.designation_id');
    $this->db->join('department','user.department_id=department.department_id');
    $this->db->join('org','user.org_id=org.org_id');
    $this->db->join('designation','user.designation_id=designation.designation_id');
    $this->db->where('your-condition`);
    $result_set = $this->db->get();
    return $result_set->result();
```

`your-selection` can be your fields that you want to select.

`your-condition` can be your conditions in an array.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel, it is helpful and help other community users.

Comment: Sorry Brother it didn't work, actually in user table there is no org id, dept id or desg id.

Comment: Then what is the connection between those tables??

Comment: Without the key in tables, it is not possible to map the tables. I mean there should be a key related to the organization and the department in the user table so that you can differentiate between the users based on these factors. Otherwise it is not possible

Comment: Hope you got my point. Otherwise, how will you know he is working for a particular department or organization??

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well I think you need something like this, join every table to get the info you need.

```
SELECT
    U.name
    ,D.desgname
    ,DPT.deptname
    ,O.orgname
FROM junction_table JT
INNER JOIN [user] U
    ON JT.userid = U.id
INNER JOIN [desi] D
    ON JT.desg_id = D.id
INNER JOIN [dept] DPT
    ON JT.dept_id = DPT.id
INNER JOIN org O
    ON JT.org_id = O.id
```